# Interface get returns null value

Tags: c#

I'm new with C# and my console application for some reason the interface IService doesn't transfer the value to the Service.  I tried to debug: _service.GetAccountName(name), name has value and then I get System.NullReferenceException for _service.GetAccountName. What I'm doing wrong here? Thank you for your patience.

Program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var newMenu = new Menu();
    newMenu.Show();

}
```

Menu

```
 public class Menu
{
    private IService _service { get; set; }

    public void Show()
    {

        var shouldStop = "";

        while (shouldStop.ToLower() != "yes")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please select one of the following options:");
            Console.WriteLine("1.Create BC \n2.View BC\n3.Edit BC\n4.Delete BC");
            var response = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (response)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("You choose to create bank account");
                    ChooseTypeOfAccount();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("You choose to view bank account");
                    var user = ChooseToViewBankAccount();
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Id:" + user.Id + "\n"+ user.Name + "\n" + user.Surname);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("User can not be found");
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("ALL USERS");
                    var allUs = _service.GetAllUsers();
                    for(var i = 0; i < allUs.Item1.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(allUs.Item1[i].Name + " " + allUs.Item1[i].Surname);
                        for(var j = 0; j < allUs.Item2.Count; j++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(allUs.Item2[i].Name + " " + allUs.Item2[i].Surname);
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("You choose to edit BC");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("You choose to delete BC");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("oops wrong choice");
                    break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("To exit type yes");
            shouldStop = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        

    }

    private User ChooseToViewBankAccount()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name");
        var name = Console.ReadLine();

        User user = _service.GetAccountByName(name);

        return user;
    }
```

Service:

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public AccountsData _accountsRepository { get; set; }

    public ChildAccountsData _childAccountRepository { get; set; }


    public Service()
    {
        _accountsRepository = new AccountsData();
        _childAccountRepository = new ChildAccountsData();
    }
```

IService

```
public interface IService
{
    User GetAccountByName(string name);
    void CreateRegularAccount(string name, string surname);
    void CreateChildAccount(string childName, string childSurname);
    (List<Account>, List<ChildAccount>) GetAllUsers();
}
```

Comment: your code calls .Show on the menu but this doesnt exists in the code you have shown. Where is the code that sets _service in the Menu class? Looks like you cut off some code from that class

Comment: I updated the code, I thought it would be easier without Show() function since it's just the menu.

Comment: so where is the code that sets _service in the Menu class

Comment: Add a constructor to your `Menu` class that sets the `_service` property, just like how you’re doing in the `Service` constructor.

Comment: I guess the second line private IService _service { get; set; } ?

Comment: grin0048, alright, but in Program.cs what should I pass into the constructor of the new Menu?

Comment: You wouldn’t need to pass anything to it.

Comment: It's asking me to put argument. Since in Menu.cs I created a new constructor:         public Menu(IService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

Comment: You can just do `_service = new Service()` in the constructor and remove the parameter.

Comment: In that case, is working. But then there is no need for the interface and I was trying to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

as currently written you need to do

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var newMenu = new Menu();
    newMenu.Service = new Service();
    newMenu.Show();

}
```

you would need ot change

```
      private IService _service { get; set; }
```

to

```
      public IService _service { get; set; }
```

but thats probably not what you want (allow callers to change Service as you go along). SO do this

```
       private IService _service = new Service();
```

PS, dont call you service `IService` call it something useful like `IDBAccess` or somethig like that.

Answer (score 0):

the most common way is to use dependency injection using a constructor.

```
 var newMenu = new Menu(new Service ());
```

but you will need to add the constructor to Menu class

```
 public class Menu
{
    private IService _service { get; set; }

   public Menu (IService service)
{
         _service = service;
}

....
}
```

or less popular way

```
var newMenu= new Menu { Service = new Service()}
```

but in this case you will have to change  Service property to public

```
public class Menu
{
    public IService Service { get; set; }
   .....
}
```